# Is it possible to fit skirting boards with screws into the wall

Tags: flooring, baseboard, skirting, board

I've been redoing my room (walls and floor) but now I am stuck on the skirting boards. Here is the room at the moment

[image: The room]

The walls are uneven and also I wanted to put the laminate floor under the skirting boards so it looks neater. However, I am told that skirting boards are usually fit with glue and nails and that means if I have to replace the floor or some part of the floor (if damaged), it will be a big mess taking out the skirting boards.

So the question is, is it even recommended to fit them using screws directly into the walls (they are brickwork with a big layer of plaster/filler? not plasterboard).

The house is early 1900s i believe (Morden, London, UK)

Thanks

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes I did leave at least 5mm on each side for most boards. Given that the walls were not straight, some are 5mm some have less and some have more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED:

I misread about the masonry walls. I've actually installed base trim using trim screws and plastic plug anchors. It works fine, but the holes in the trim are larger.

---

ORIGINAL:

Glue is only used for joints, and nails pull out of the wall fairly easily when the boards are removed. They can then be pulled through the boards from the back side so the boards can be reused.

You can certainly use screws, but the holes will be much larger and therefore more difficult to conceal.

In general, trim isn't installed with the expectation that it'll be regularly removed.

Comment: Screws would actually be harder to find and remove assuming the heads get covered.  Agree, only use nails.

Comment: Given that the walls are plaster and masonry, maybe small amounts of construction adhesive would be better.

Comment: Ah. I misread that. That changes things. I've actually installed base trim with trim screws and anchor plugs.

Comment: So if I go down the adhesive route and nails. What's the best way to make sure the boards are straight? The walls are not straight at all! This is why I originally wanted to use screws, so I can control where the board needs more tension and where it needs less.

Comment: First, I'm not sure how you're going to use Nails & Masonry. Then, trim usually fits to the walls. It doesn't stay straight and have gaps behind it.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, we managed to do them with screws and they fit fine.